# Leaflet not getting correct bounding area for NASA GIBS map in EPSG:4326 CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, epsg

I am creating an app using Leaflet and [GIBS](https://nasa-gibs.github.io/gibs-api-docs/map-library-usage/).  The trouble I am having is when I try to use a link from [EPSG4326](https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml) the bounding box is incorrect.

When I use [ESPG3857](https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg3857/best/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml) the bounding box is correct.  Draw over Australia.[image]
Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sy35agLf/) of what I have to far.

Here is the [Incorrect bounding area](https://jsfiddle.net/a7983qpe/)

The only difference is I added `crs:L.CRS.EPSG4326` to the `L.map` object.  Drawing over Australia gives incorrect data.[image]

See link for full code.

using tile layer `//gibs-{s}.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg3857/best/MODIS_Terra_CorrectedReflectance_Bands367/default/2020-12-19/GoogleMapsCompatible_Level9/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpg` with default gets expected bounding area when drawn on map.

Using tile layer `https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/MODIS_Terra_CorrectedReflectance_Bands367/default/2020-12-19/250m/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpeg` with option `crs:L.CRS.EPSG4326` is giving unexpected results.

I am looking at MODIS_Terra_CorrectedReflectance_Bands367. ESPG3857 ows:Bounding is below, while ESPG4326 does not have that block.

```
<ows:BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857">
<ows:LowerCorner>-20037508.34278925 -20037508.34278925</ows:LowerCorner>
<ows:UpperCorner>20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</ows:UpperCorner>
</ows:BoundingBox>
```

Comment: The raster layer matches the CRS.  On the incorrect link I am using raster layer `https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/MODIS_Terra_CorrectedReflectance_Bands367/default/2020-12-19/250m/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpeg` and added `crs:L.CRS.EPSG4326`

Comment: I overlooked that. But if you look at the EPSG:4326 map at zoom level 0, you'll see that Earth image does not cover whole of the two tiles, and that's the reason for coordinate problems. Also have in mind that tiles are 512x512.

Comment: I printed the titleSize and it is 256 which is the same as the working code.  I did set the tile to 512 but still wasn't giving me what I was expected.  Changing the tileSize to 412 seems to be more accurate.  But I am worried that is not the correct course of action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By luck I stumbled upon one of my previous dealings with NASA Blue Marble maps. Solution is to use proj4js for Leaflet (https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) and define your own `EPSG:4326` projection.

Projection definition looks like this:

```
 var my_EPSG_4326 = new L.Proj.CRS(
  "EPSG:4326",
  "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs", {
    origin: [-180, 90],
    resolutions: [
      0.5625,
      0.28125,
      0.140625,
      0.0703125,
      0.03515625,
      0.017578125,
      0.0087890625,
      0.00439453125,
      0.002197265625
    ],
    bounds: L.bounds(
      L.point(-180, -90),
      L.point(180, 90)
    )
  }
);
```

Since tiles have size 512x512 and actual max zoom is 8, map and layer definition then looks like this:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  editable: true,
  crs: my_EPSG_4326
}).setView(startPoint, 2);

var tilelayer = L.tileLayer('https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/MODIS_Terra_CorrectedReflectance_Bands367/default/${tileDate}/250m/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpeg', {
  noWrap: true,
  tileSize: 512,
  maxZoom: 8, attribution: 'Data \u00a9 <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"> OpenStreetMap Contributors </a> Tiles \u00a9 HOT'
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you, I stumbled across a similar post.  I will bookmark this post and the link and thanks for your help with this issue.